# Seeking address for 1930s migrant to Brazil from Lebanon?

Tags: immigration, 1930s, brazil

I'm looking for my grandfather who migrated to Brazil around 1930s, his name is Mahmoud Chahine. I believe he worked in the coffee industry in Sao Paulo.

I am seeking an address in Brazil where he lived. He emigrated from Lebanon and I believe he was born around 1890. His father's name is Hammady and his mother's name is Sikna.

Comment: Hi Iman, what are your looking for about your grandfather?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. What country did Mahmoud emigrate from? When was he born?

Comment: The answer on the duplicate is for the right time period (1808-1940) and mentions the state of São Paulo too so hopefully will give you a starting point from which to commence research and then frame a more focussed question, if you need further help.

Comment: Are there any websites to search?

Comment: I need an address in Brazil where he lived. He emigrated from Lebanon and I believe he was born around 1890. His father's name is Hammady and his mother's name is Sikna.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: What is the last record you have of him in Lebanon?  Do you have any records of him in Brazil or just word of mouth within your family?

Comment: I do not have any records of him in Lebanon of brazil. Some elderly family members say that he has two sons and one daughter. The daughter's name is Fatme and they live in Sao Paulo. That's all they know.

Answer (score 1):

I could not locate one specific Mahmoud Chahine, but honestly did not go over all records. If you did not give a try yet at [FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/search/hr/search), do it, there are several records for Chahine from Lebanon arriving at Sao Paulo.

I tried specifying parents name using the data you provide but again was not successful. I would not rely in filtering by parents in an initial search, though.